# TYPO3: getTypoLink_URL alternative (generating url aliases)

Tags: typo3

Is there an alternative way of getting the URL to a page (by id) apart from using `cObj->getTypoLink_URL`?

I'm trying to create URL aliases, so a page can have multiple URLs (for example "/about" could actually point to "/corporate/home/about").

I'm currently hooking into realurl's hook `decodeSpURL_preProc`, but TSFE and cObj are not initialised at that point therefore calling `cObj->getTypoLink_URL` doesn't work.

I should add that the url alias should not redirect to the original url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create RealURL aliases("Redirects"), you can create a database query that fetchs the url aliases, you have created.

Have a look in the realurl redirects table.

Comment: the redirects table still needs the destination, so I would hit the same problem (not being able to generate the original page url). Also, realurl redirects to the alias, I'm trying to mask it (show the same page on 2 urls without redirecting).

Answer (score 1):

just use the folowing code to generate the link.

You might want to load localconf.php.

```
class Devlib {

    static function _link($id,$urlParameters='',$target='') {
        $cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
        return $cObj->getTypoLink_URL($id,$urlParameters,$target);      
    }      
}
```